# Metric and the triangle inequality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

Let $A,B$ be finite subsets of the natural numbers. If we let $d(A,B)=\sum_{x\in A\mathbin\Delta B} 2^{-x}$, where $A\mathbin\Delta B=(A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)$ is the symmetric difference between $A$ and $B$, does $d$ satisfy the triangle inequality? That is, if $A,B,C$ are finite, open subsets of the natural numbers, is $d(A,B)\leq d(A,C)+d(C,B)$? Or do we have to assume that the subsets are disjoint for the triangle inequality to be satisfied?

Comment: (1) What do you mean by *open*? (2) Have you tried some examples of the triangle inequality to get an idea of what happens when the sets are and are not disjoint?

Comment: Why do you want to restrict to finite sets? The series $d(A,B)$ always converges for any $A,B\subseteq \mathbb{N}$. And yes, what do you mean by open?

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram and look at $A \mathbin{\Delta} B$ as well as $A \mathbin{\Delta} C$ and $C \mathbin{\Delta} B$. Can you see that $A \mathbin{\Delta}B \subseteq (A \mathbin{\Delta}C) \cup (B \mathbin{\Delta}C)$? Then prove this.

Comment: @Martin: I have already been drawing (a lot of) Venn diagrams, but your expression holds only if the subsets are disjoint, right?

Comment: Forget about the open-part, by the way.

Comment: The inclusion I wrote holds without assumptions on $A,B,C$. Draw just the standard one with three sets representing $A,B,C$. Color the three sets $A \mathbin\Delta B$ as well as $A \mathbin\Delta C$ and $B \mathbin\Delta C$. The first picture [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) might help seeing why the inclusion I claim holds.

Comment: Is $B\cap C\subseteq A\Delta C$ and $A\cap C\subseteq C\Delta B$?

Comment: I see it now (by former Venn diagrams were wrong)! (forget about my last post). Thank you, Martin.

Comment: Or $A \Delta B= (A \Delta C) \Delta (C \Delta B) \subset (A \Delta C) \cup (C \Delta B)$

Answer (score 1):

Martin provided one answer in the comments. Here’s another way to show that $d$ is a metric. For each $A\subseteq\Bbb N$ let $\chi_A$ be the [indicator (or characteristic) function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of $A$. Then

$$d(A,B)=\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}2^{-n}|\chi_A(n)-\chi_B(n)|\;$$

for any $A,B\subseteq\Bbb N$. (There’s no need to restrict oneself to finite subsets.) Hence

$$\begin{align*}
d(A,B)&=\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}2^{-n}|\chi_A(n)-\chi_B(n)|\\
&\le\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}2^{-n}\Big(|\chi_A(n)-\chi_C(n)|+|\chi_C(n)-\chi_B(n)|\Big)\\
&=\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}2^{-n}|\chi_A(n)-\chi_C(n)|+\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}2^{-n}|\chi_C(n)-\chi_B(n)|\\
&=d(A,C)+d(C,B)\;.
\end{align*}$$

This is actually just a special case of the proof that if $\{\langle X_n,d_n\rangle:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a family of metric spaces such that each $d_n$ is bounded by $1$, and $X=\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}X_n$, then the function

$$d:X\times X\to\Bbb R:\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}2^{-n}d_n(x_n,y_n)$$

satisfies the triangle inequality. (It is of course a metric on $X$.) Here each of the spaces $X_n$ is a copy of $\{0,1\}$ with the metric inherited from $\Bbb R$, and the map $A\mapsto\chi_A$ is an isometry.